# How can I use Cancan to grant users privileges with exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

In my app I have a model called Profile, which contains profile information for people.  I also have a User model, and some users manage content on the site, and their privileges are managed with the Cancan gem.  Each user has one profile, but there are many profiles not associated with users.  Suppose I have two classes of users, a large amount of "editors" who can manage content, and a few "admins" who can do anything.  I want to make it so editors can manage (create, edit, and delete) profiles *unless* that profile belongs to another user.  How can I do this with Cancan?

I know how to limit a user's ability, such as

```
can :manage, Profile, :user_id => user.id
```

but I want something like a logical condition, like "can manage profile, unless that profile is associated with a user and that user is not the current user".

Answer (score 1):

@Laurens is correct. Use cancancan.
You can also pass a block to the can or cannot method, for example:

```
cannot :manage Profile do |p|
  cond1 = method_that_returns_boolean
  cond2 = method_that_returns_boolean
  cond1 && cond2
end
```

which means that the user cannot manage the profile if cond1 and cond2 are both true.

Answer (score 0):

CanCan is out of date.

I suggest you look into https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/

To get what you want (untested)

```
can :manage, Profile, :user_id => [nil, user.id]
```

For more complex cases you can define abilities with blocks:
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks